# Position of behold in a sentence

Tags: meaning

With this sentence I'm a bit confused:

> And when our ancestors finally did make their first cave
>   paintings, what were the first designs? A downward slash, lightning bolts through the bottom
>   and middle—behold, the Running Man.

Specifically, I can't get it why the author used the word "behold" so I can't imagine the drawing that he described.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The author is being somewhat dramatic. He starts with a plain, technical description of the individual markings on the cave wall. At "behold", the sentence changes tone to be less literal and becomes his interpretation of what the markings as a set represent.

Comment: He is metaphorically inviting the reader to look at the finished drawing.

Comment: @RichF so by downward slash and etc he is trying to describe the final drawing?

Comment: @nadasaboori yes. Then he completes his description by having us picture a running man.